# Question editor bug when use code in blockquote

Tags: support, markdown

It seems we can use code sample in blockquote, so I tried this:

````
> ```pub trait A {}
pub trait B: A {}```
````

Or

````
> ```pub trait A {}
> pub trait B: A {}```
````

Or

````
> ```   pub trait A {}
> pub trait B: A {}```
````

They all show the same thing, I can't align the two row.

> `pub trait A {}
>   pub trait B: A {}`

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “align the two row”? Make a code block? You do that by indenting the code with four spaces plus the one for the blockquote, so `>`, five spaces, line of code. Fenced code blocks aren’t supported on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, four spaces can do this indenting, but the way above still seems strange.

Comment: @McGrady Backticks here only do inline code, which doesn't preserve newlines. Only indenting creates a full code block with newlines preserved.